# Does there exist $X$, $k$, $M$ such that $N(X)$ is diffeomorphic to open punctured unit ball.

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

For a $k$-manifold $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^M$, define its tangent bundle $T(X) \to X$ and the normal bundle $N(X) \to X$. Let $B$ denote the open punctured unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e., $B = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 0 < ||y|| < 1\}$. Prove or disprove the following.

1. There exist $X$, $k$, $M$ such that $T(X)$ is diffeomorphic to $B$.
2. There exist $X$, $k$, $M$ such that $N(X)$ is diffeomorphic to $B$.

for (1), tangent bundle is always even dimensional manifold. Here open punctured unit ball is a 3 dimensional manifold so there doesn't exist any manifold which has tangent bundle diffeomorphic to open punctured unit ball.

for (2) I guess $\mathbb{S}^2$ is the correct manifold , but the ambient space should be $\mathbb{R}^6$ to make the normal bundle 3 dimensional manifold. Am I correct?

Comment: Your punctured ball is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$, so $\mathbb{S}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the answer for (2). Note that the dimension of $N(X)$ equals **the sum of the dimensions of $X$ and the normal fiber**, in particular the dimension of $N(X)$ is always $M$ for a $k$-manifold $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^M$.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @Zerox